# No IP address for rootless Docker daemon when running "ip addr show"

Tags: docker, ip

When I use the [Docker daemon in rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/), I don't see any Docker IP address when running `ip addr show`.

When I use the [Docker daemon as root](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/), the IP address of the interface `docker0` is shown when running `ip addr show`.

How can I get the IP address of a rootless Docker daemon?

Comment: But why do you need it? Can't you use `docker exec`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I need it to forward requests to this IP.

Comment: Looks like it's described in your link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#known-limitations